# Capitalize a letter regardless of spacing

Tags: c++

Hi guys I have a question on this code I'm practicing cstrings with. I made a program that capitalizes the first letter of a sentence inputted by the user. I assumed that the user would put a space after placing a period so if the user typed in "im from. seattle" the output would be "Im from. Seattle". But if the user didn't put a space after the period it would be the second letter that would be capitalized and not the first like this "Im from.sEattle" . How do I get it to capitalize the first letter only regardless of spacing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype> //strlen, touper
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
void funct(){
    int length = 50;
    char input[length];

    cout << "Sentence Capitalization Machine Mk.1.\n";
    cout << "Type a sentence for me to capitalize." << endl;
    cin.getline(input, length);
    cout << endl;

    input[0] = toupper(input[0]);
    int i=0;
    while (i < strlen(input)){
               i++;
               if (input[i] == '.'){
                input[ i + 2 ] = toupper(input[ i + 2 ]);
               }
   };

cout << input << endl;
}
int main(){
    funct();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see a '.' therefore I will skip 0 or more whitespace and capitalize the next letter I see. If I don't see a letter (e.g. I see a number) I will forget I ever saw that '.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype> //strlen, touper
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
void funct(){
    int length = 50;
    char input[length];

    cout << "Sentence Capitalization Machine Mk.1.\n";
    cout << "Type a sentence for me to capitalize." << endl;
    cin.getline(input, length);
    cout << endl;

    input[0] = toupper(input[0]);
    int i=0;
    while (i++ < strlen(input)){
               if (input[i] == '.' && input[i+1] == ' ' &&  i+2<strlen(input)){
                input[ i + 2 ] = toupper(input[ i + 2 ]);
               }else if(input[i] == '.' &&  i+1<strlen(input)){
                   input[ i + 1 ] = toupper(input[ i + 1 ]);
               }
   };

cout << input << endl;
}
int main(){
    funct();
    return 0;
}
```